# Powers of Dirichlet series

Tags: number-theory

Let's consider Dirichlet series in their convergence region
$$D(s) = \sum_n \frac{\lambda(n)}{n^s},$$

where the $\lambda(n)$ are complex coefficients satisfying Hecke-like relations, say
$$\lambda(m)\lambda(n) = \sum_{d|(m,n)} \lambda\left( \frac{mn}{d^2} \right).$$

We can develop and get an expression of the square is terms of Dirichlet series, namely
$$D(s)^2 = \sum_d \frac{1}{d^{2s}}\sum_n \frac{\lambda(n)\sigma(n)}{n^s},$$

where $\sigma$ is the divisor function. By hand we can find some tricky change of variables allowing to give reasonable expressions for $D(s)^3$ or $D(s)^4$. My question is: is there any general formula for the powers $D(s)^n$, written in form of Dirichlet series making use of only one coefficient $\lambda(?)$ and divisor/artihmetic functions otherwise?

Comment: Write its Euler product